Search-AzQuery querying authorizationresources returns 0 records
I want to query all the builtin Azure role definitions using Search-AzQuery. I have the Az.ResourceGroup module v1.0.0 installed.
This query works fine in the Azure Portal's Azure Resource Graph Explorer and returns 5 records:
authorizationresources | where type == "microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions" | where properties["type"] == "BuiltInRole" | limit 5

If I run the same query locally using Search-AzQuery (or az graph query for that matter), I get zero records.
Search-AzGraph -Query 'authorizationresources | where type == "microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions" | where properties["type"] == "BuiltInRole" | limit 5'

However, if I remove the second where, then it does return records.
Search-AzGraph -Query 'authorizationresources | where type == "microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions" | limit 5'

I've also tried the =~ operator (to ignore case when comparing) but that makes no difference.
What am I doing wrong?

Search-AzGraph -Query "authorizationresources | where type == 'microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions' | where properties['type'] == 'BuiltInRole' | limit 5" -UseTenantScope 

You should add UseTenantScope, I tried a lot and found that this method works.
Why it works:
roledefinitions has the resource id some like this /providers/Microsoft.Authorization/RoleDefinitions/aabbc5dd-1af0-458b-a942-81af88f9c138, which not be related to a certain subscription. It is a Basic tenant query reference

Has the difference to Basic query, need to pass subscriptionIds array.


When you run in local you should not run like the way you run, you will get 0 records as below:

To get correct results, you have to use command as below and followed Microsoft-Document:
az graph query -q "
authorizationresources 
| where type == 'microsoft.authorization/roledefinitions' 
| where properties['type'] == 'BuiltInRole' 
"


Also refer my answer in SO-Thread.
Edit:
Use this command :
Search-AzGraph -Query " 
authorizationresources 
| where type =~ 'microsoft.authorization/roleassignments'
"

Edit2:
$rith = Search-AzGraph -Query "
authorizationresources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.authorization/roleassignments'
"
$rithwik = $rith | Where-Object { $_.properties.principalType -eq 'X' }
$rithwik

I do agree with @wenbo, UseTenantScope at the end it will work

I tried your query with Search-AzQuery and it still returns 0 records.

Try with az graph query -q as it worked for me

That does work for me too. So is the only difference that you separated it over multiple lines?
It would be nice to get it to work with Search-AzGraph too

Yes, that is the difference and it will only work like that

Is the requirement to use multiple lines documented somewhere? I don't see that mentioned on the page you link to

No it is not, but it gives records when  given like that

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
